# Tradingview avoid repeating label

Tags: tradingview-api

I´m using this script to lalbel bars in Tradingview. How can I avoid the Green and Red arrows repeating?. and just to show them in the first bar of the first signal?

```
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtH1W.jpg)
//@version=5
indicator("PowerX", overlay = true)

fast = ta.ema(close,12)
slow = ta.ema(close,26)
macd = fast - slow
signal = ta.ema(macd,9)
rsi = ta.rsi(close,7)
sto = ta.stoch(close,high,low,14)

IsBuy() => macd>signal and rsi>50 and sto>50
IsSell() => macd<signal and rsi<50 and sto<50 
IsSide() => macd<signal or rsi<50 or sto<50 
barcolor(IsBuy() ? color.green : IsSell() ? color.red : IsSide() ? color.white : na)

if IsBuy() 
alert("Compra")
else if IsSell() or IsSide() 
alert ("Venta")

plotchar(IsBuy(), "Go Long",  "▲", location.abovebar, color.green, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(IsSell() or IsSide(), "Go Long",  "▼", location.belowbar, color.red, size = size.tiny)
```

Attached is the scrip.